# Difference between Minicart and Cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I want to know the difference between Mini cart and Cart in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no major differences between **cart and MiniCart**.

There the are same entity of same module `Magento_Checkout  & Magento_Quote`

The main difference between two is that MiniCart showing to all page at **header top right corner`** and  Where Cart is a specific Page where current basket's all item of a current customer is shown.

Another difference, No of item show at the mini cart is limit,  depends on the setting.

Where at cart page show, basket all items.

If you are a developer, then there are main different two is that

MINicart data manage using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

And where Cart page data depends on  Block class and layout files.